# target elements of a row from a button in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this table created dynamically in JQuery:

[image]

I'd like the "Send" button from each row to target elements such as "Reg. Key" val., "assignee name" (if any value is inputted) belonging to the same row. I added a class to the "send" buttons and I managed to target each "send button's" id with "this". How do I target the other elements in the same row ?

Thanks much.

JQuery code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            $('#kg_table').append('<tr id = "row'+i+'">'+
                                    '<th>'+prs[i]+'</th>'+
                                    '<th><select id = "usrct'+i+'"name="userCat">'+
                                        '<option value="noo">Select Category</option>'+
                                        '<optgroup label="Medical Categories"></optgroup>'+ 
                                        '<option value="mds">Medical Student</option>'+
                                        '<option value="mdr">Medical Resident</option>'+
                                        '<option value="mdf">Medical Fellow</option>'+
                                        '<optgroup label="Dental Categories"></optgroup>'+
                                        '<option value="dts">Dental Student</option>'+
                                        '<option value="dtr">Dental Resident</option></select>'+
                                    '</th>'+
                                    '<th><input id = "asg'+i+'" type="text" ></th>'+
                                    '<th><input id = "eml'+i+'" type="text" ></input></th>'+
                                    '<th><button type="button" id = "bsnd'+i+'" class = "bsnd">Send</button></th>'+
                                    '<th><button type="button" id = "bprn'+i+'" class = "bprn">Print</button></th>'+
                                '</tr>');
            }
```

Comment: share your html also the click event handler

Comment: Hi Johny, I just updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your click button handler is like

```
$('#kg_table').on('click', '.bsnd', function(){
    var $this = $(this), $tr = $this.closest('tr'), cat = $tr.find('select').val(), name = $tr.find('input:eq(0)').val(), email = $tr.find('input:eq(1)').val();

    //do something with the values
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/X2kAs/)

Comment: Johny, thank you for your promptness. Answer up-voted and testing now.

Comment: Johny, one quick question, if I want to include the value of the reg key (first th) from the table, how would I do that ? I tried ".closest('th');" but is not getting anything back.

Comment: @Nactus `$tr.find('th:first').text()`